# how i can exit my app to home screen and add are you sure want to exit button

Tags: java, android

sorry . i am a newbie and may sound stupid 
i have a app made using an app template .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ipllive2018.streaming

in the app when i click menu item it will load corresponding items but when i click back it exits without going to home screen. i want help regaring how to fix it .

second i also want to add a exit button like "u want to exit " like that

I am really sorry . i have searched and tried many codes . i am absolutely a newbie and its limiting my actions . i am pasting my app source file

> 

```js
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment activeFragment = null;
        if (adapter != null)
            activeFragment = adapter.getCurrentFragment();
        if (drawer != null && drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (activeFragment instanceof BackPressFragment) {
            boolean handled = ((BackPressFragment) activeFragment).handleBackPress();
            if (!handled) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fragment, i suggest to use fragmentTransaction's addToBackStack(). From your HomeFragment, do this

```
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new otherFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and on your back press, check your FragmentManager's stack count

```
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit app?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.show();
} else {
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```